# Proc parameters

Tags: mainframe, jcl

We are having some proc steps which are using control cards that contain cics region names.
Procs are present in Endevor.Previously we had endevor macros which used to change the region names as per the env. But now onwards endevor macros are disablled.Is there any other way to change the region names in proc.

e.g: If control card has below data at 1st env A:-
TEST**A**
After moving this to env B in endevor it was getting changed to:-
TEST**B**

we are using TWS scheduller for executing the job.Is there any facility available in TWS which we can use to change these type of parameters in proc.

Thanks and Regards,
Saisha.

Comment: Maybe if you provide an example of the JCL/procs and what changes between them?

Answer (score 1):

You can use TWS variables that can be used to customize anything in a jcl that you are running. The variables cannot be used directly in proc JCL because it is only read in by JES2/3.

```
//*%OPC TABLE__NAME=(_table name_)
```

The above allows you to specify a variable table in TWS that can be used for the substitution.

[The Job Tailoring Section of this manual provides details of what is possible](http://publibz.boulder.ibm.com/cgi-bin/bookmgr_OS390/BOOKS/eqqtmg30/1.23?SHELF=EQQTBK30.bks&DT=20090716161030)

```
//*%OPC SCAN
//*%OPC SETVAR TATF=('TEST')
//LISTCAT  EXEC  PGM=IDCAMS
//SYSPRINT DD  SYSOUT=*
//SYSIN    DD  *
   LISTCAT ENT(VSAM.&TATF) ALL
```

The above is an example of TWS variables to override what is in a SYSIN, but you do need to change the JCL and it needs to be inline.

The &TATF will be replaced by TEST when the JCL is subbed by TWS

Comment: Thanks Deuian.But I cant edit my job.I am looking for something which can  change the control card values at run time.I tried with REXX code,but as our control cards are present in endevor libs we dont have edit access to it.Please let me know if by any means I can change the control card values at job execution time.

Comment: Saisha, I don't know exactly what you mean, do you have an example of the jcl and what you want changed?

Comment: Sorry Deuian for replying so late. Actually I was looking for replacing some fields in control cards that are accessed in SYSIN in cataloged proc. like having symbolic parameters in control card.

Comment: Saishe, I am still not sure what exactly you are looking for, can you give an example?  Is the SYSIN a member or inline?

Answer (score 1):

You could specify the value(s) you require for these parameters in your execution JCL on your EXEC PROC= statement.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.But we have third party procs which we cant change and these are taking region names via sysin only.I just wanted to know if we can have any run time parameters in control cards which will be replaced at job execution time.